# Dropping columns in data.table by name pattern

Tags: r, data.table

In R, one can easily drop columns from a data frame according to name pattern: see [How to drop columns by name pattern in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666226/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-pattern-in-r) and [Subset data to contain only columns whose names match a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587334/subset-data-to-contain-only-columns-whose-names-match-a-condition), for example.

```
> df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3), A2=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,2,3), BG=c(2,2,3))
> df[, -grep("A", colnames(df))]
  B BG
1 1  2
2 2  2
3 3  3
```

But directly applying the solutions to a data.table doesn't work.

```
> dt <- data.table(A=c(1,2,3), A2=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,2,3), BG=c(2,2,3))
> dt[, -grep("A", colnames(df))]
[1] -1 -2
```

What can be done?

Comment: Set them to NULL: `dt[, grep("A", names(dt)) := NULL]`

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked that.

Comment: To use the original approach, you'd need `with = FALSE`, e.g. `dt[, -grep('A', names(dt)], with = FALSE]` or `dt[, grep('A', names(dt), invert = TRUE), with = FALSE]`

Answer (score 5):

As Rich Scriven points out, `dt[, grep("A", names(dt)) := NULL]` works.

```
> dt <- data.table(A=c(1,2,3), A2=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,2,3), BG=c(2,2,3))
> dt[, grep("A", names(dt)) := NULL]
> dt

   B BG
1: 1  2
2: 2  2
3: 3  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `data.table::patterns` function:

```
df <- data.table(A=c(1,2,3), A2=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,2,3), BG=c(2,2,3))
df[, .SD, .SDcols = !patterns("A")]
```