# remove columns based on a pattern in their names

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
colnames(df) <- c("A",  "B",  "C",  "MO_A",   "MO_B",   "D",   "F",  "MO_D")
```

Now I wanna remove all the columns that start with "MO_"

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop columns by name pattern in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666226/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-pattern-in-r) and [Subset data to contain only columns whose names match a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587334/subset-data-to-contain-only-columns-whose-names-match-a-condition)

Comment: Try `df[,!grepl('^MO_',colnames(df))]`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
for(n in colnames(df)) {
if(grepl("MO_", n)) df[[n]] <- NULL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regex](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) to get the columns of interest then index the data frame with a negative index to remove them.

With a logical index:

```
df <- df[, !grepl('MO_', colnames(df))]
```

With a numeric index:

```
df <- df[, -grep('MO_', colnames(df))]
```