# Grouping columns and creating a list output

Tags: r, regex

I am new to R. I have a R dataframe of following structure:

```
     164_I_.CEL 164_II.CEL 183_I.CEL 183_II.CEL 2114_I.CEL
   1       4496       5310      4492       4511       2872
   2        181        280       137        101         91
   3       4556       5104      4379       4608       2972
   4        167        217        99         79         82
   5         89        110        69         58         47
```

I want to group the columns which have "_I.CEL" in the column name.

I need a list output like `NI, NI, I, NI, I`

where NI means Not I.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop columns by name pattern in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666226/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-pattern-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of `ifelse` and `grepl` looking for the required pattern in the column `names`.

```
ifelse(grepl("_I\\.CEL", names(df1)), "I", "NI")
#[1] "NI" "NI" "I"  "NI" "I"
```

where `df1` is your data frame.

Or use `fixed = TRUE`

```
ifelse(grepl("_I.CEL", names(df1), fixed = TRUE), "I", "NI")
```