# How to drop columns with column names that contain specific string?

Tags: r

```
 name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria")
 agenn <- c(23, 41, 32)
 agelk <- c(23, 41, 32)
 agepm <- c(23, 41, 32)
 df <- data.frame(name, age,agelk,agepm)
 print (df)
```

I would like to drop columns with column names that contain `c("epm","enn","jkk")`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop columns by name pattern in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666226/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-pattern-in-r)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(-contains(c("epm", "enn", "jkk")))
#>    name agelk
#> 1   Jon    23
#> 2  Bill    41
#> 3 Maria    32
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table` and `%like%`

```
df[,!colnames(df) %like% paste0(c("epm","enn","jkkk"),collapse="|")]
   name agelk
1   Jon    23
2  Bill    41
3 Maria    32
```

Comment: Edited to ensure we drop as per OP and also to use `%like%` once for more efficiency. Revert edit if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Using `matches`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select(-matches('epm|enn|jkk'))
#   name agelk
#1   Jon    23
#2  Bill    41
#3 Maria    32
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a `base` R approach:

First of all your code ;)

```
name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria")
agenn <- c(23, 41, 32)
agelk <- c(23, 41, 32)
agepm <- c(23, 41, 32)
df <- data.frame(name, agenn,agelk,agepm)
```

Create your values do drop:

```
drop_val <- c("epm","enn","jkk")
```

You can check with `grepl` if a string exists in another. So let's loop for every string you want to remove and compare if it exists in `colnames(df)`. Well and if none of your strings fits, you keep them -> otherwise remove.

```
 df[!grepl(paste0(drop_val,collapse="|" ),names(df))]
```

Output:

> ```
>    name agelk
> 1   Jon    23
> 2  Bill    41
> 3 Maria    32
> ```

Comment: Edited to remove for loops, and avoid explicit `==FALSE` checks. Revert back if you please.