# Drop columns that match a pattern, with an exception

Tags: r, contains

I have example data as follows:

```
dat <- mtcars
dat$add <- dat[,1]
dat$last <- dat[,1]
names(dat) <- c("fraction_low", "fraction_medium", "fraction_high", "fraction_low_2000", "fraction_medium_2000", "fraction_high_2000","fraction_low_2001", "fraction_medium_2001", "fraction_high_2001","fraction_low_comb", "fraction_medium_comb", "fraction_high_comb", "last")
```

I would like to remove all columns/variable names that have `fraction` and `low`, `medium`, or `high` in their name, **except** the columns/variable names that **also** have `comb` in the name.

I found a lot of good answers for removing columns with a certain pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666226/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-pattern-in-r). For example:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% select( -( contains("fraction") & ( (contains("low") | contains("medium") | contains("high") ) )))
```

But how should I implement and exception to such a pattern?

Desired output:

```
desired_output <- dat[,10:13]

                    fraction_low_comb fraction_medium_comb fraction_high_comb last
Mazda RX4                           4                    4               21.0 21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag                       4                    4               21.0 21.0
Datsun 710                          4                    1               22.8 22.8
Hornet 4 Drive                      3                    1               21.4 21.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
 dat %>%
   select(-matches(c("fraction", "low", "high", "medium")), contains("comb"))
```

---

Or may use

```
dat %>% 
   select(-matches("fraction_(low|medium|high)_(?!comb)|fraction_(low|medium|high)$",
     perl = TRUE))
```